# Angularjs, get ionic radio button value for ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button, angularjs-ng-show

i'm working with ionic framework and i'm stuck with a problem.
i have to display some views (in this case are just label "WIFI" and "LAN") when related buttons are pressed.

```
<ion-content ...>
<ion-radio ng-repeat="item in reti" ng-value="item.value" ng-click="networkChange(item)">
   {{item.text}}
</ion-radio>

<ion-item ng-show="item.value == 'wifi'">WI-FI</ion-item> 
<ion-item ng-show="item.value == 'lan'">LAN</ion-item>
```

My .js file

```
.controller('connessioneCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.reti = [
    { text: "Wi-Fi", value: "wifi" },
    { text: "Lan", value: "lan" }
];

$scope.data = {
    data: "wifi"
};

$scope.networkChange = function (item) {
    console.log("Selected network: ", item.value);
    };
};
```

my problem is ng-show, possibly the item.value passed, its not working (not showing WI-FI or LAN. Any suggestions? Thanks for help

Comment: your function `networkChange` isn't actually assigning the value to something

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
<ion-item ng-show="data == 'wifi'">WI-FI</ion-item> 
<ion-item ng-show="data == 'lan'">LAN</ion-item>
```

and

```
$scope.data = "";
$scope.networkChange = function (item) {
    console.log("Selected network: ", item.value);
    $scope.data = item.value;
};
```

Comment: Solved, in .js file i change $scope.data={ data: "wifi" };  in $scope.data={network: "" };    after that in the <ionic-radio .. > i define a ng-model="data.network"    then in ng-show="data.network == 'wifi' " and  ng-show="data.network == 'lan' "

Comment: that is what I said, the variables are just a little different